# Cannot open .xls file after Office update

Tags: c#, excel, xslt

I am not able to open .xls file after last Excel update. When I double click on file, Excel starts but do not show any message.

In the past it showed "The file you are trying to open, 'filename.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?" and I was able to open it.

I am generating this file with C# and xsl stylesheet. When I open file in Notepad++, add space somewhere and save it - file is suddently possible to open.

How to fix this? Where can be a problem?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Do you have any macros in the xls file?

Comment: I can delete everything, remain just:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <asdf>asdf</asdf>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

and still not able to open. Only when I resave it with Notepad++